# PHP update form that updates database information only if there is an input in that particular field using PDO

Tags: php, html, sql, database, pdo

I am currently working on a form that uses PHP and SQL to update information in a database. It is functioning properly and updating the information but the issue is... is that it updates everything, including fields that I didn't even put any input in which means it will only update a particular row in the database and leave the others blanks... I need it to just change information from a field with an actual input and leave it if there is no input.

Here is the PHP and SQL code:

```
try {

$deleteRecId = $_GET['id'];
$update_event_name = $_POST['updateName'];
$update_event_location = $_POST['updateLocation'];
$update_event_date = $_POST['updateDate'];

include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

// new data
$sql = "UPDATE events SET event_name='$update_event_name', 
event_location='$update_event_location', event_date='$update_event_date' 
WHERE event_id=$deleteRecId";

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and here if the form:

```
<form class="update-form" action="<?php echo $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">

  <p id="input-headers">Event Name</p>

  <p id="update-input-field-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="updateName" value="">
  </p>

  <p id="input-headers">Event Location</p>

  <p id="update-input-field-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="updateLocation" value="">
  </p>

  <p id="input-headers">Event Date</p>

  <p id="update-input-field-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="updateDate" value="" placeholder="01/01/2000">
  </p>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="updateBtn">

</form>
```

So to sum up I need this application to only update information of a field with an actual input and if the form field has no input I need that database info to remain the same. I appreciate any help with this as I am pretty new to these concepts... thanks!

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_update

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understand how that example would work with my code. It seems more complicated than it needs to be... but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: That's the **only proper way**, as opposite to your code full of errors and sql injection

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said I'm new to this lol.

Comment: but you take the liberty to judge whether some code is "more complicated than it needs to be" or not

Comment: I'm not building Facebook, I'm building a simple form to complete an assignment. Therefore yes, your solution is way too complicated for something this simple. And the solution I came up with was 3109238012 times simpler than yours and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: so don't call yourself a "new to this" if you really consider yourself a smart aleck who knows everything. remember my words the day your "3109238012 times simpler" solution backfired. Have a good day

Comment: If I was developing a website for Amazon I'd highly consider your answer since it's the 'only proper way'. But it isn't, it's a school assignment lol. And thanks for the compliment I am smart. You can delete the Aleck part and keep it to yourself :)))))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

I found a really handy solution to this! Here is how I implemented it into my code.

```
$sql = "UPDATE events SET event_name=IF(LENGTH('$update_event_name')=0, event_name, '$update_event_name'), event_location=IF(LENGTH('$update_event_location')=0, event_location, '$update_event_location'), event_date=IF(LENGTH('$update_event_date')=0, event_date, '$update_event_date') WHERE event_id=$deleteRecId";
```

It basically just checks whether the string is empty or not. If it's empty it won't be updated. If it isn't empty it'll go through with the update! Very simple way to achieve this effect when creating an update form.

Answer (score -1):

Using your current code structure, you can do this.

1. Use SQL to select * from event ID. Populate your update_event_xxx with the parameters.
2. If $_POST[xx] is blank, ignore. Else, update_event_xx = $_POST[xx]

Comment: Could you possibly update the answer where you actually implement the code within my code? It would help out a ton. Thanks!